# Duplicate Symbols in Phonegap Urbanairship Plugin for iOS

Tags: phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

I am in the middle of integrating UA into my Phonegap/iOS application using the UA Phonegap plugin https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push.

Unfortunately, I can not get it to work. Even the sample project fails to build. The problem is a duplicate symbol during linking. Please note: i did not include any additional headers, libs, etc. I am just trying to build the iOS sample project.

The clashing symbol seems to be rooted in the `ASI* (ASIHttpRequest, ASIAuthenticationDialog, etc)` library, which has been integrated into UA. Surprisingly, the clashing happens between both UA libs (`libUAirship-1.3.2.a` and `libUAirshipPush-1.3.2.a`).

Linker output: `ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UA_ASIAutorotatingViewController in /Users/b/Downloads/urbanairship-phonegap-ua-push-9b7a89b/ios-sample/Airship/libUAirshipPush-1.3.2.a(UA_ASIAuthenticationDialog.o) and /Users/b/Downloads/urbanairship-phonegap-ua-push-9b7a89b/ios-sample/Airship/libUAirship-1.3.2.a(UA_ASIAuthenticationDialog.o) for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

How can this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appeared for me when I add the flag "-ObjC" in my target settings at "Other Linker Flags".

Check it, i need the flag for an another library but if it's not your case...

Comment: I ended up removing this flag yesterday. Afterwards I had about 40+ linker errors (missing symbols). After i added the required frameworks one by one, the build succeeded.